# JQuery toggle() method didn't affect the other duplicates elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a sample program that will show the content using `toggle()` but the problem is it only affects the first content and the others doesn't.

**JS :**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#p").hide();
    $("#pp").hide();

    $("#button").click(function(){
        $("#p").toggle();
        $("#pp").toggle();
    });
});
```

**HTML :**

```
<details>
    <summary>show</summary>

    <p>a</p>
    <p>a</p>
    <p>a</p>

    <button id="button">Toggle</button>
    <p id="p">This is a paragraph with little content.</p>
    <p id="pp">This is another small paragraph.</p>

</details>
<hr>
<details>
    <summary>show</summary>

    <p>a</p>
    <p>a</p>
    <p>a</p>

    <button id="button">Toggle</button>
    <p id="p">This is a paragraph with little content.</p>
    <p id="pp">This is another small paragraph.</p>

</details>
<hr>
<details>
    <summary>show</summary>

    <p>a</p>
    <p>a</p>
    <p>a</p>

    <button id="button">Toggle</button>
    <p id="p">This is a paragraph with little content.</p>
    <p id="pp">This is another small paragraph.</p>

</details>
```

How can I fix that.

**[HERE is my fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/26ydLkLp/1/)**

In my actual program I put those(enclose in details tag) in php include to lessen multiple codes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`id` should be unique in same document try to replace duplicate ones by global `class`, check example below.

Use `parent().find()` to select just the paragraphs (`.p` and `.pp`) related with clicked button (captured by `$(this)`) details :

```
$(this).parent().find(".p,.pp").toggle();
```

Hope this helps.

```js
$(function(){
  $(".p,.pp").hide();
  
  $(".button").click(function(){
    $(this).parent().find(".p,.pp").toggle();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<details>
 <summary>show</summary>

 <p>a</p>
 <p>a</p>
 <p>a</p>
 
 <button class="button">Toggle</button>
 <p class="p">This is a paragraph with little content.</p>
 <p class="pp">This is another small paragraph.</p>

</details>
<hr>
<details>
 <summary>show</summary>

 <p>a</p>
 <p>a</p>
 <p>a</p>
 
 <button class="button">Toggle</button>
 <p class="p">This is a paragraph with little content.</p>
 <p class="pp">This is another small paragraph.</p>

</details>


<hr>
<details>
 <summary>show</summary>

 <p>a</p>
 <p>a</p>
 <p>a</p>
 
 <button class="button">Toggle</button>
 <p class="p">This is a paragraph with little content.</p>
 <p class="pp">This is another small paragraph.</p>

</details>
```